# Icons from GLYPHICONS don't load

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

You would like to use the Bootstrap in Symfony2.
However, in the rental server that I owe, less command can not be used.
So from http://getbootstrap.com/, was placed css you have downloaded, font, etc..
However, glyphicon does not appear.
Will're something wrong way of setting?

```
MyBudle
  + Resources
      + Public
         + Css
         + Fonts
         + Js
```

page.html.twig

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets '@LouteBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts '@LouteBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% stylesheets
        output='fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
        '@LouteBundle/Resources/public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
    %}
    {% endstylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        output='fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
        '@LouteBundle/Resources/public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
    %}
    {% endstylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        output='fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
        '@LouteBundle/Resources/public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
    %}
    {% endstylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        output='fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
        '@LouteBundle/Resources/public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
    %}
    {% endstylesheets %}
</head>
```

use glyphicon

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    </a>
```

Comment: please check that you add jquery, bootstrap javascript nd css file correctly....

Comment: Oops!That'right.but,not load glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff and glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf. NOT Found. 404 Error.

Comment: use your jquery and bootstrap.min.js file in the footer(end of the html code but before </body></html>), and also put jquery.js file above the bootstrap.min.js file because if you put the jquery.js file below bootstrap.min.js file then some of the bootstrap function won't work...

Comment: @village what server are you using? Apache2, nginx?

Comment: many times: "app/console cahce:clear" that I was resolved Once implemented.

Comment: Why your are using js with fonts?

Comment: You should use bootstrap on CDN. Its simple
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`